# Can I detect the frame rate of a video using built in programs or tools?

Tags: macos, video, metadata

I want to match the frame rate of a video I am editing to a project. But I don't know the frame rate.

Is there an easy way to check the frame rate of a video using built-in tools or programs?

Comment: What video editor are you using?

Comment: @theonlygusti I use Screenflow, iMovie, and am learning Premiere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In QuickTime Player

1. press cmd-i (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> or Window > Show Movie Inspector)
2. expand the Video section
3. see the "Encoded FPS" value

[image]

[image]